# Make breadcrumbs with multiple <a> tags word break and wrap to another line

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Just wondering if this is possible. So I am using Japanese kanji and kana in this web app mobile version.

So all breadcrumbs except the last one are links to previous pages. Since each breadcrumb is a link, I am having trouble making them display inline like the picture and also break mid-breadcrumb to wrap to a new line.

I can make them break at the end of a breadcrumb link and start a new line, but I want to try to break a breadcrumb mid-text and wrap it to a new line and continue all subsequent breadcrumbs on the new line also.

The container div would be set to 100% width.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, in modern web browsers, *it seems like `word-break:break-all;` is already the default style automatically for Eastern languages.*  [No CSS or JS in this Demo](https://jsbin.com/hoyaremadi/1/edit?html,output), and it works perfectly (tested Chrome).

But if you did have problems with wrapping, or if you wanted to guarantee compatibility across devices and browsers, then use some CSS.  Specifically...

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Take a look at [a full working demo](https://jsbin.com/huxoreyuyu/edit?html,output) (or, [a full working Japanese demo](https://jsbin.com/wutafebuha/edit?html,output), ([or yet a third working Japanese demo with your exact characters](https://jsbin.com/demixepiju/edit?html,output)))...

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    p {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>loooooooooooooooooooooong woooooooooooooooooordddddddddddddddddddd.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like this...

[image: Long word wrap.]

[image: Long word wrap - Japanese Text]

Of course, you may want to wrap it to a specific length.  In that case, add this CSS style: `p { width:500px; }`, and then it'll wrap after 500px, etc..

Comment: That example is just wrapping text. I understand how to do that, but that is not the problem. Please read my problem description again and look at the updated pic.

Comment: @frootloops: Hey, thanks for looking.  I updated the demo to have japanese text, and I uploaded an image of the result.  It looks very similar, though I have used spaces while you have greater-than signs.

Comment: @frootloops read your own question again, I cant derive what you actually want to do

Comment: @frootloops: I have added a third demo, it has the precise exact characters you're trying to display, Japanese and &gt;'s.  What's wrong?  https://jsbin.com/demixepiju/edit?html,output

Comment: I just edited the problem explanation and illustrated what I need to do in the pic. I know how to wrap text. That is not the problem. The problem comes when you wrap each breadcrumb in an 'a' tag and a 'span' to make it a link. Now you are dealing with a bunch of spans in a row and trying to make a span word-break and wrap.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger But I need each breadcrumb to be a LINK, meaning an 'a' tag wrapped in a span. Your example is just one long string of text. There are no links.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions. I actually figured out how to do it. Long story short, I just had to wrap all of the a tags inside a p tag and use flex wrap.

Comment: Hi, frootloops: This is how you add a link element to HTML, `<a>`.  I didn't include that in the example, because I thought it was trivial.  Here, works great: https://jsbin.com/hoyaremadi/1/edit?html,output